# Getting data into a template

Tags: nodes

How do I add data into a table into my node--course.tpl.php?

I would like to mimic the table on this page where it has course ID and info:
http://cie.austin.utexas.edu/uex-cm/courses/acc-310f-foundations-accounting-online
[image]

to look like this:
http://uex.webhost.utexas.edu/coursedetails.cfm?OutID=3040
[image]

Should I use a view or a block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install [DisplaySuite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) (DS). Views are for "lists of things" and Blocks are for rendering various pieces of content on parts of a page -- not necessarily fields of a content type.

I would also recommend [FieldGroup](http://drupal.org/project/field_group) and [FieldGroupTable](http://drupal.org/project/field_group_table) which are 3rd party additions to DS. FieldGroup allows you to *group* fields in your content type into various visual outputs -- out of the box:

> - Fieldsets
> - Horizontal tabs
> - Vertical tabs
> - Accordions
> - Divs
> - Multipage steps: Note: This is only client side.
> - HTML5 elements
> - Html elements

By also having field_group_table installed you may group the desired fields of your content type into a small table on the page as well. The field_group_table page says:

> This module extends the Field Group module and provides a "Table"
>   group format, which renders the fields it contains in a table. The
>   first column of the table contains the field labels and the second
>   column contains the rendered fields.

With DS you should be able to create a layout of you content type as desired in your 2nd picture. Maybe you may need to tweak the CSS for the table output, I'm not sure.

There are many online video demos for DS online, and there are Documentation pages linked in the Resources sidebar for each of these modules.

Answer (score 0):

For the first image if its content type you can create a view of that content type with fields 
as shown in the table.

Comment: Thanks! So how do I link that view from another view?

Comment: which view do you want? can u elaborate a bit?